# ClearInterval() not working, its not stopping

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with `clearinterval`, it does not work the way I did it. Can someone spot the problem and explain it to me?

Here is JS code:

```
<script>

    var br = "<br / >";

    function funkcja() {
        var i = 0;
        var intervalId = setInterval(function(){
            document.write(i+1 + "- obieg pętli" + br);
                i++;
            }, 1000);
        if(bbb == 10) {
                clearInterval(intervalId);
                }
    }

</script>
```

And HTML object:

```
<p id="ppp" onclick="funkcja();"> Kliknij mnie </p>
```

Comment: And don't use `document.write`. Use the DOM.

Comment: Also can I suggest, whatever development enviroment your using, you use a good linting sytem,. That error would have then been picked up.

Comment: What is `bbb`?.

Comment: bbb variable is not declared

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since you have your `clearInterval` inside a condition `if(bbb == 10)` that condition is only checked when `funkcja()` executes, i.e only when you press `p#ppp`

in addition, `bbb` is not defined perhaps?

try writing it like this:

```
function funkcja() {
    var i = 0;
    var intervalId = setInterval(function(){
        document.write(i+1 + "- obieg pętli" + br);
            i++;
            if(i == 10) {
               clearInterval(intervalId);
            }
        }, 1000);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

bbb var is not declared. Add ClearInterval Function inside setInterval

```js
    var br = "<br / >";
    var bbb;
    function funkcja() {
        var i = 0;
        var intervalId = setInterval(function(){
            document.write(i+1 + "- obieg pętli" + br);
                i++;
                bbb = i;
               if(bbb == 10){
                  clearInterval(intervalId);
               }
            }, 1000);
     }
```

```html
<p id="ppp" onclick="funkcja();"> Kliknij mnie </p>
```